# Why did Jonesy say, "Better to be from Pittsfield than go back to it"?

Tags: dreamcatcher

Jonesy gives a punishment to a student, Mr. Defuniak
who is from Pittsfield:

> Jonesy: You missed the test. And since you were ill, why not write me
>   an essay instead? 3000 words on the short-term results of the  Norman
>   Conquest.
>
> Mr. Defuniak: Yes, sir.
>
> Jonesy: **Better to be from Pittsfield than go back to it**.

I didn't understand what actually he meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct quote, according to IMDB, is "Pittsfield's a better place to be from, than go back to."

Long story short, it's a small town. A good place to raise children (safe), but not a place where you'll make your fortune due to most of the work being blue collar. Furthermore, given the context, he's also implying that, without a proper education, Mr. Defuniak will never have the means or opportunity to succeed outside of town.